# Chance of 100th coin flip being heads

Tags: probability, gambling

Assuming I have flipped 99 coins all tails, what is the chance of the 100th coin being heads?

Yes I know it's still 50%, but is there any other formula that could help explain the risk/probability of a heads/win if I only start playing after X amount of losses? I would like to know how much better 'chances' I have of a heads if I start playing after a certain amount of losses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the event that we throw $n$ tails in a run, and $Y$ the event we throw heads,

Using Bayes theorem we can write

$$P(Y|X) = \frac{P(X|Y)P(Y)}{P(X)} = \frac{\large(\frac12\large)^n\frac12}{\large(\frac12\large)^n} = \frac12$$

So it doesn't matter how many times we lose, the chance of a head remains the same.

Comment: Thanks, and I understand that part, I was just wondering in the law of averages, if i flipped 99 tails, i would 99 extra heads in the future (if the sample size is large enough). Is there any way I can count this extra chance from history? (perhaps instead of just counting the 100th flip, if i keep counting until i get a head if that makes it any different)

Comment: You say : 'I would 99 extra heads in the future'. It is wrong. Your coin has no memory. It doesn't remember it had 99 extra tails in the past and it would 99 extra heads in the future. Your coin knows only one rule : at each toss, give Head or Tail, with probability 50%

Comment: The Law of Averages states only that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{|H|}{|T|} = 1$. It doesn't say how the heads and tails are distributed,

Comment: @Primoz56 Once the first coin lands on a tail, the number of accessible sample points in the sample space has been cut in half.  By the time the first $99$ coins land on tails, the only remaining accessible sample points in the sample space are $T^{99}H$ and $T^{100}$, and there is no such thing as needing "extra heads in the future."

Answer (score 2):

In the ideal world that mathematicians normally inhabit, there are perfectly fair coins.  With these, the previous $99$ tails would be totally irrelevant and the $100$th throw would be just as likely to be heads as the first.

In the real world, if I saw $99$ heads in a row then I would seriously doubt the fairness.  Either the coin was biased or the person throwing it was able to manipulate it.  You could use methods from statistics to judge whether the coin might really be fair.  I have not done the calculations but it will be very unlikely.

Comment: This gets to the heart of the question. The other answers **assume** that the probability of heads is fixed, and it's just a matter of applying the laws of probability. In reality, observing a run of results like this would make us question the assumption, not simply apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the probability that your coin has two tails. (Basically the probability that you've been tricked.) Now, the probability that your last coin will be tails is this:

$$p+(1-p)2^{-100}$$

out of the probability to get the $99$ tails in the first place:

$$p+(1-p)2^{-99}$$

so the conditional probability that you will get tails is:

$$\frac{p+(1-p)2^{-100}}{p+(1-p)2^{-99}}=1-\frac{1-p}{2^{100}p+2(1-p)}\ge 1-\frac{1}{2^{100}p}$$

which is *very* close to $1$, unless $p$ is of the order of magnitude of $2^{-100}$ or smaller! In other words, this confirms our intuition that, if there is *any* (reasonable) chance you've been tricked, you can well expect to have tails again.

(Of course, when $p=0$, the formula above gives $\frac{p+(1-p)2^{-100}}{p+(1-p)2^{-99}}=\frac{1}{2}$, as expected.)

You can expand this reasoning to the case where the coin might not really have two tails but be biased, and if there is any chance that the coin is heavily biased, this chance will again blow up by the fact that there were $99$ tails in a row. I would not provide a complete computation here.